# Advanced filtering in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I have a large amount of data in Excel and I need to filter it with the following logic:

[image]

If an ID has a certain value, then I need to exclude all the rows with such an ID.
In the following example if this value would be 'c', then I need to exclude all rows with corresponding ID = '3', meaning row 4 and 7 and the results should look like this:

[image]

Comment: And what did you try to do? where is your code?

Comment: Following that logic, if value is `a` then there is no rows to show, because value `a` is related to ID 1, 2 and 3, so all rows would be hidden?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Yes, exactly. It's just an example.

Comment: Weird logic, but anyways, you need it. Please, post the code you have tried and where are you stuck. You tagged the question as excel-vba, so you must have some code problems.